# Find a closed formula to the sum: $\sum_{k=2}^{50}k (k-1){50 \choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

please help me with the formula, tried everything I know and I'm stuck!

$$\sum_{k=2}^{50}k(k-1){50 \choose k}$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you simplify the quantity inside the summation, using the definition of the binomial coefficient?

Comment: Hint: $\binom{50}{k} = \frac{50!}{k!(50-k!)} = \frac{(50)(49)48!}{k(k-1)(k-2)!(48-(k-2)!} = \frac{(50)(49)}{k(k-1)}\binom{48}{k-2}$

Comment: Using the same as in the answers you already received, you could show that $\sum_{k=2}^{n}k(k-1){n\choose k}=2^{n-2} (n-1) n$

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice trick to finding closed forms like this. Consider $(1+x)^{50} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{50}{50\choose k}x^k$ by the binomial theorem. If we take the first derivative of both sides, we get $50(1+x)^{49} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{50}{50\choose k}kx^{k-1}$. Repeat to get $50(49)(1+x)^{48} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{50}{50\choose k}k(k-1)x^{k-2}$. Evaluating at $x=1$ should get you your answer: $50(49)(2^{48})$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the identity $\binom{n}{k}=\frac nk\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^{50}k(k-1)\binom{50}{k}
&=\sum_{k=2}^{50}k(k-1)\binom{50}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{50}50(k-1)\binom{49}{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{50}50\cdot49\binom{48}{k-2}\\[6pt]
&=50\cdot49\cdot2^{48}
\end{align}
$$